# Stuck in transformClassesWithDexForXXXX in some gradle version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I encounter version problem when update latest gradle and gradle-plugin.
The build process will stuck in transformClassessWithDexForXXXX step

Wait 10 minutes still not build successfully.

**Latest version :**

Android Studio -> 2.3.1

Gradle -> 3.3

Android Plugin Version -> 2.3.1

[image]

**Old version : (It can works)**

Android Studio -> 2.3.1

Gradle -> 2.1

Android Plugin Version -> 2.1.x

Still do not know what is the root cause .... Q_Q

Answer (score 0):

finally.. the same issue refer to

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37116789

Remove testCoverageEnabled is work but not make sense.. wait for official answer

2017/04/18 Updated :
It took three days to narrow down what file make this problem, but so weird.

The below java codes will happen this problem(remove it will work successfully), but I do not have any idea.

This is piece codes from [DiskLruCache.java](https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/DiskLruCache.html)

```
public class HaHa {
private final LinkedHashMap<String, Entry> lruEntries
        = new LinkedHashMap<String, Entry>(0, 0.75f, true);


private int valueCount = 100;

private void processJournal() throws IOException {
    for (Iterator<Entry> i = lruEntries.values().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Entry entry = i.next();
        if (entry.currentEditor == null) {
            for (int t = 0; t < valueCount; t++) {
            }
        } else {
            for (int t = 0; t < valueCount; t++) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public final class Editor {

    private Editor() {
    }
}

private final class Entry {
    private long[] lengths;
    private Editor currentEditor;

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting, change traversal in one of the loops. e.g. :

```
public class HaHa {
private final LinkedHashMap<String, Entry> lruEntries
        = new LinkedHashMap<String, Entry>(0, 0.75f, true);


private int valueCount = 100;

private void processJournal() throws IOException {
    for (Iterator<Entry> i = lruEntries.values().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Entry entry = i.next();
        if (entry.currentEditor == null) {
            for (int t = valueCount + 1; t > 0; t--) {
            }
        } else {
            for (int t = 0; t < valueCount; t++) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public final class Editor {

    private Editor() {
    }
}

private final class Entry {
    private long[] lengths;
    private Editor currentEditor;

}}
```